# Meteor: Cordova Facebook Native Login working in Development mode but not in Production Mode

Tags: cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins, meteor-blaze, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm using this package: btafel:accounts-facebook-cordova
and this cordova plugin : cordova-plugin-facebook4@1.5.0

When I do meteor run android-device or ios-device, it is working as expected ( It is fetching user info from the native Facebook app installed, and if the Facebook app isn't installed it opening up a small modal asking the user to sign in into Facebook).

Now the problem is that when I deploy this application and build it into APK (or on XCode - App Store), the native login isn't working as expected and is showing up in an ugly in-app browser (which is a huge turn off to the users). Here's a screenshot of the in-app browser login (which shouldn't happen) :

[image: Ugly in app browser]

So basically the problem is the login is working fine under development mode, but it isn't when the app is built. And I have tried passing in the production server url into meteor run android-device, in which, interestingly, the login is working fine.

Please help. Thanks!